# How to define command line options in my sql systemctl service

Tags: mysql, utf-8, deployment, systemctl, digital-ocean

I have a mysql install on Digital ocean cloud.
And by default it's working with system ctl service.

I need to run the server with those options :

[image]

That have taken from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-server.html).

So I've tried to edit this file:
nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf

But after I'm adding the values, and try to restart the service it says:

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

I have tried some things, without success.
[image: example of the file]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The second row doing the problem at the file  `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`.

Only this row should be presented:

```
character-set-server=utf8mb4
```

and **not**

```
character-set-server=utf8mb4
collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

as was. (this isn't needed)

[Therefore, the following three commands all have the same effect:](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-server.html)